# Roots of $x^6-ax^5+ax^4-ax^3+ax^2-ax+a$

Tags: polynomials, roots

For $a>0$, how many positive real roots can $x^6-ax^5+ax^4-ax^3+ax^2-ax+a$ have?

A quick graph in desmos strongly suggests it only has 2 positive real roots at most, but how can we prove it?

Comment: Descartes Rule of Signs?

Comment: multiply by $x+1$ and then apply Descartes rule of signs.

Comment: @TheBestMagician I did think about it once but wasn't able to understand how to apply it (since it can't work directly ofcourse)

Comment: @achille hui thank you, I like your method the best so if you convert your comment to an answer I could accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since only the terms with *odd* powers of $ \ x \ $ in the polynomial function $ \ f(x) \ = \ x^6 - ax^5 + ax^4 - ax^3 + ax^2 - ax + a \ $ with $ \ a \ > \ 0 \ $ has negative coefficients, it is clear that $ \ f(x) \ > \ 0 \ $ for $ \ x \ \le \ 0 \ \ , $ so any real zeroes must be positive.  This is confirmed by the Rule of Signs (no negative zeroes, even number of positive zeroes), but it does not tell us whether there are six, four, two, or no positive real zeroes.

We may start by remarking on the following properties:

•   $ \ f(0) \ = \ a \ \ \ ; \ \ \ f(1) \ = \ 1 \ \ \ ; \ \ \ f(a-1) \ = \ 1 \ \ \ ; $

$ \quad f(a) \ = \ a^5 - a^4 + a^3 - a^2 + a \ = \ a·(a^4 - a^3 + a^2 - a + 1) \ = \ \large{a·\frac{a^5 \ + \ 1}{a \ + \ 1}} \ \normalsize{> \ 0} \  \ \ ; $

$ \quad  f(a+1) \ = \ 2a^5 + 8a^4 + 14a^3 + 12a^2 + 6a + 1 \ > \ f(a) \ > \ 0 \ \ \ ;  $

•    $ \ f'(x) \ = \ 6x^5 - 5ax^4 + 4ax^3 - 3ax^2 + 2ax - a \ \ \ ; \ \ \ f'(0) \ = \ -a \ \ \ ; \ \ \ f'(1) \ = \ 6 - 3a \ \ \ ; $

$ \quad f'(a-1) \ = \ a^5 - 6a^4 + 15a^3 - 20a^2 + 15a - 6 \ = \ \large{\frac{(a \ - \ 1)^6 \ - \ 1}{a}} \ \ \ .  $

We will define $ \ f_6(x) \ = \ x^6 - ax^5 \ = \ x^5·(x - a) \ \ , \ \ f_4(x) \ = \ a·(x^4 - x^3) \ = \ ax^3·(x - 1) \ \ , $ $ f_2(x) \ = \ a·(x^2 - x) \ = \ ax·(x - 1) \ \ , \ $ so that $ \ f(x) \ = \ f_6(x) + f_4(x) + f_2(x) + a \ \ . $  We observe that, with $ \ a \ > \ 0 \ \ , $

• $ \quad f_2(x) \ < \ 0 \ $ only for $ \ 0 \ < \ x \ < \ 1 \ \ , \ $ with a minimum value $ \ f_2 \left(\frac12 \right) \ = \ \large{-\frac{a}{4}} \ \ ; $

• $ \quad f_4(x) \ < \ 0 \ $ only for $ \ 0 \ < \ x \ < \ 1 \ \ , \ $ with a minimum value $ \ f_4 \left(\frac34 \right) \ = \ a·\left(\frac34 \right)^3·\left(-\frac14 \right) $ $ \quad \quad = \ \large{-\frac{27a}{256} \ > \ -\frac{a}{9}} \ \ ; $

• $  \quad -1 \ < \ f_6(x) \ < \ 0 \ $ for $ \ 0 \ < \ x \ < \ 1 \ \ ; \ $ its  absolute minimum value is $ \ f_6 \left(\frac{5a}{6} \right) $ $  \quad \quad = \ \left(\frac{5a}{6} \right)^5·\left(-\frac{a}{6} \right) \  = \ \large{-\frac{3125a^6}{46656} \ \approx \ -\frac{1}{15}·a^6} \ \ . $

We apply this first for $ \ 0 \ < \ a \ < \ 1 \ \ . \ $ Since $ \ 0 \ < \ x^6 \ < \ ax^5 \ \Rightarrow \ 0 \ < \ x \ < \ a \ \ , \ \ f_6(x) \ $ is a very small negative quantity over $ \ 0 \ < \ x \ < \ a \ \ , $ then becomes positive and grows rapidly as $ \ x \ \rightarrow \ 1 \ \ . $  The minimum value of $ \ f(x) \ $ is approximated by $  \ a - \frac{a}{4} -  \frac{a}{9} \ = \ \frac{23}{36}·a \ \ ; \ $ combining this with our observations above, $ \ f(x) \ $ is then positive   in the interval $ \ 0 \ \le \ a \ \le \ 1 \ \ . $  Since all of the "component functions" $ \ f_2 \ , \ f_4 \ , \ $ and $ \ f_6 \ $ are positive for $ \ x \ > \ 1 \ \ , \ f(x) \ $ has **no** real zeroes for these values of $ \ a \ \ . $

The situation begins to change for $ \ 1 \ < \ a \ < \ a_{crit} \ \ . $  The contribution to the minimum value of $ \ f(x) \ $ from $ \ f_6(x) \ $ becomes rapidly more important since that term grows increasingly negative as the *sixth* power of $ \ a \ \ . \ $ The absolute minimum of $ \ f(x) \ $ is $ \ f(1) \ = \ 1 \ \ $ for $ \ a \ = \ 2 \ \ , \ $ but for larger values of $ \ a \ \ , $ the minimum decreases.  For $ \ a \ = \ 3 \ \ , $ the minimum of $ \ f_6 \ $ is $ \ f_6 \left(\frac{5·3}{6} = \frac52 \right) \ \approx \ -48.8 \ \ \ . \ $  We have $ \ f(1) \ = \ 1 \ \ , \ \  f'(1) \ = \ 6 - 3·3 \ = \ -3 \ \ , \ \ f(3 - 1) \ = \ f(2) \ = \ 1 \ \ , \ $ and $ \ f'(3 - 1) \ = \  f'(2) \ = \  \frac{(3 \ - \ 1)^6 \ - \ 1}{3} \ = \ 21 \ \ , \ $ telling us that the function has a turning point in $ \ 1 \ < \ x_{min} \ < \ 2 \ \ $ with a negative value.  Since $ \ f_2(x) \ , \ f_4(x) \ > \ 0 \ $ for $ \ x \ > \ 1 \ \ , $ the component function $ \ f_6(x) \ $ is entirely responsible for taking $ \ f(x) \ $ to negative values, and $ \ x^6 \ - \ ax^5 \ $ has only two real zeroes, so we may conclude that $ \ f(x) \ $ has only **two** positive real zeroes for $ \ a \ > \ a_{crit} \ \ . $

From the properties above, we can say something about the locations of those zeroes.  Since $ \ f(a - 1) \ = \ 1 \ $ and $ \ f'(a - 1) \ $ has a very large *positive* value for $ \ a \ > \ a_{crit} \ \ , $ one zero is *extremely close* to $ \ x \ = \ a - 1 \ \ $ (Newton's Method yields approximately $ \ a - 1 - \frac{1}{a^5} \ ) \ . $  As $ \ f(1) \  = \ 1 \ $ and $ \ f'(1) \ = \ 6 - 3a \ \ , $ the other zero is near to $ \ x \ = \ 1 \ \ $ ("Newton" estimates it as $ \ 1 + \frac{1}{3a - 6} \ ) \ . $

Curiously, by using a graphing tool, we find that $ \ a_{crit} \ \approx \ 2.74 \ \ , $ close to $ \ e \ \ ; \ $ here, $ \ f(x) \ $ has just one real zero (multiplicity 2) at $ \ x \ \approx \ 1.492 \ \ . \ $ Application of second derivatives can say more about the "intervals of concavity" and will confirm that that there are just two real zeroes for $ \ a \ > \ a_{crit} \ \ , $ but only with some amount of computational assistance.

$$ \ \ $$

**ADDENDUM (7/18) --**

To follow up on the comment by **achille hui** (since it describes a device worth knowing about), if we multiply the expression for $ \ f(x) \ $ by a factor $ \ ( x + 1 ) \ \ , $ we obtain

$$ F(x) \ \ = \ \ (x \ + \ 1) \ · \ ( \ x^6 \ - \ a·[ \ x^5 \ - \ x^4 \ + \ x^3 \ - \ x^2 \ + x \ - \ 1 \ ] \ ) $$  $$ = \ \ x^7 \ + \ (1 - a)·x^6 \ + \ a  \ \ . $$

When we apply the Rule of Signs to this polynomial, we find that we have two cases.  For $ \ 0 \ < \ a \ < \ 1 \ , \ $ the "middle" coefficient is positive, so there are no "sign-changes", so we conclude that there are no positive real zeroes for $ \ F(x) \ \ $ and thus also for $ \ f(x) \ \ . \ $  A transition is predicted, however, as the middle coefficient becomes *negative* for $ \ a \ > \ 1 \ \ , $ so we now have two sign-changes; $ \ F(x) \ $ and $ \ f(x) \ $ may now have either two or zero positive real zeroes.

[We also observe that $ \ F(-x) \ = \ -x^7 \ + \ (1 - a)·x^6 \ + \ a \ $ has one sign-change regardless of the value of $ \ a \ \ , \ $ so $ \ F(x) \ $ has one negative real zero.  But *we* are responsible for the presence of that zero, since we "intruded" a factor of $ \ ( x + 1) \ \ . $  So we confirm our earlier conclusion that $ \ f(x) \ $ has no negative real zeroes.]

This technique indicates the transition from no positive real zeroes to two possible ones, but does not tell us much about the value of $ \ a \ $ at which that occurs.  In fact, this is not simple to resolve analyticaly. One estimate I attempted was to take $ \ a_{crit} \ $ as roughly the value at which the minimum of $ \ f_6 \ $ is equal to the sum of the minima of $ \ f_2 + f_4 \  \ , $ so that $ \ f_6 \ $ is beginning to determine the "depth" of the total function minimum and "force" the presence of two real zeroes:

$$ \frac{1}{15}·a^6_{crit} \ \ \sim \ \ \frac{13}{36}·a_{crit} \ \ \Rightarrow  \ \ a_{crit} \ \ \sim \ \left(\frac{65}{12} \right)^{1/5} \ \ \approx \ \  1.40 \ \ . $$

So other than telling us that $ \ a_{crit} \ $ is greater than 1 and small, we get a better idea of how $ \ f(x) \ $ "behaves" from the properties listed above.  We likely need to characterize$ \ f''(x) \ $ in detail in order to understand this transition.

Comment: wow this is literally perfect, although I'd solved by both methods already this is very much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

A graphical method with the advantage that one can grasp the problem visually.

Consider the curve and the horizontal line below with resp. equations

$$y=f_1(x)=\dfrac{x^5-x^4+x^3-x^2+x-1}{x^6}$$
$$\text{and} \ \ y=f_2(x)=k \ \ \text{with} \ \ k:=\dfrac{1}{a}>0$$

[image]

The curve of $f_1$ has a local maximum at $$(x^*,y^*)\approx(1.4918, 0.3649)$$

The abscissas $x$ of the intersection points are such that

$$f_1(x)=f_2(x)$$

which is equivalent to the initial polynomial parametric equation. Therefore,

- if $0<k<y^*$: 2 (positive) solutions (the line intersects twice the curve.
- if $k=y^*$: 1 solution $x=x^*$.
- if $k>y^*$: no solution.

Otherwise said, in terms of $a=\frac1k$

- if $a>1/(y^*)\approx 2.74 $: 2 (positive) solutions (the horizontal line intersects twice the curve).
- if $a=1/(y^*)$: 1 solution $x=x^*$.
- if $a<1/(y^*)$: no solution.